# Interpreting an extension with a wildcard IN an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, wildcard

Why does this work:

```
$VideoExtensions = @('.mp4','.mov','.mpg','.mts','.3g2','.3gp','.avi','.mkv','.flv','.wmv')
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.Extension -match '.jp*' -or
    $_.Extension -in $VideoExtensions
}
```

But not this:

```
$PicExtensions = @('.jp*','.png')
$VideoExtensions = @('.mp4','.mov','.mpg','.mts','.3g2','.3gp','.avi','.mkv','.flv','.wmv')
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.Extension -in $PicExtensions -or
    $_.Extension -in $VideoExtensions
}
```

The `.jp*` wildcard is completely ignored.  If I used -like will it catch files that are not exactly .png?  I'm iffy about using -like operators.

Comment: The [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) of `-in` will only return `true` if there is an **exact match**. If you are concerned about wildcards, `-match` might be a better option. It allows for `regex`

Comment: In your first code, `-match` should be `-like`. For the second code, you can make it work by setting the `$PicExtentions` to the actual extensions you want to catch: `$PicExtensions = '.jpg','.jpeg','.png'`.  As a sidenote, you don't need `@()` here.

Comment: Side note: `.jp*` is a wildcard pattern, but the `-match` operator is for regular expressions, not wildcards (that would be `-like`). Your clause `$_.Extension -match '.jp*'` only works incidentally, because `.jp*` happens to *also* be a valid regular expression (which is not true for all wildcard expressions) and regular expressions are not automatically anchored at the beginning/end of strings (unlike wildcard expressions). By this happenstance the regex match matches includes everything `$_.Extension -like '.jp*'` would match (but it actually matches more than that).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using regular expressions instead of lists of strings for something like this.

```
$PicExtensions = 'jp.*|png'
$VideoExtensions = 'mp4|mov|mpg|mts|3g2|3gp|avi|mkv|flv|wmv'

$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.Extension -match "^\.(${PicExtensions})$" -or
    $_.Extension -match "^\.(${VideoExtensions})$"
}
```

---

If you wanted to continue using lists of strings (not recommended) you'd have to compare each element individually (which is bound to perform very poorly), because the `-contains` and `-in` operators allow only exact matches whereas you want to do wildcard matches.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $ext = $_.Extension
    ($PicExtensions | Where-Object {$_ -like $ext}) -or
    ($VideoExtensions | Where-Object {$_ -like $ext})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just specify multiple patterns in the path, if it didn't have to be literal.

```
$pic = echo *.jp* *.png
$vid = echo *.mp4 *.mov *.mpg *.mts *.3g2 *.3gp *.avi *.mkv *.flv *.wmv

get-childitem -path ($pic + $vid) -recurse
```